# two or more jQuery conflicts in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This type of question has been posted long ago but i am having some more doubts about jQuery.

I am having these several scripts in my code:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery Date picker-->
<script type ="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.jdpicker.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Date picker end-->
<!--Pop up jquery scripts-->
 <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/modalPopLite.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/modalPopLite.min.js"></script>
<!--Pop up jquery scripts ends -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- small image slider start-->
<link href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/small_slider/js-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>css/small_slider/js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- small image slider ends-->

<!-- sliderman.js for top image slider-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/sliderman.1.3.7.js"></script>
```

the `jquery.min.js` and `jquery.js` do same functions??

When I added **popup jquery** it was working fine, but previously added **datepicker** stopped working.

alas...

afterwords when I added the **image slider jquery** then **popup** stopped working..

and I badly need all of the scripts in page.

Comment: `Jquery.min.js` is a minified/compressed version of jquery and `jquery.js` is unformatted javascript eg: braces and such are kept in place

Comment: What's the question? You only need one jQuery. jquery.min.js is just a minified version of jquery.js.

Comment: title of post makes no sense ... php and jQuery run in completely different environments and have absolutely nothing to do with each other

Comment: This is a painful question to look at. You need to do some legwork and figure out what the issue is from the errors in the console. If you're not able to google and get answers that you can understand, you're probably in over and your head and need someone who does.

Comment: messy code, is the main issue here, solve this and it solves it all

Comment: when i remove the jquery.min.js and jquery.js nothng changed.. the error remains there.. what can i do, so that i can use all of the jquery plugins?

Comment: @KAsh keep `jquery.min.js`

Comment: I think your main problem is those jquery for datepicker,popup,image slider ,, is they are using different jquery lib.. some use old ones and other used the new ones... that why from start it works and when you add another one the previous doesnt .

Comment: @class i kept the jquery.min.js and now datepicker is not working.. i inspected with firebug.. but its showing all scripts are included successfully..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jquery.min.js` is the minimized version of `jquery.js`. ie in `jquery.min.js` every white spaces are cleared from `jquery.js`. So they both are same.

In your set of jquery files many may use `jQuery` or `$` variables. Thats why conflict occurs.

To avoid it, you can create an `additional.js` file and just write `$.noConflict();` or `jQuery.noConflict();` according to what causes conflict.

If it doesnot solves the problem, examine the `js` files and make sure you defines `jquery.js` ahead of every subsidiary files that uses your datepicker, pop up etc. **You must include it only once.**

Comment: Wow.. thank you so much.. it worked..I also have to reposition the jquery call.. and all is well nw.. Thnks...

Answer (score 1):

You can't include jQuery more than once in page. You have it included multiple times(3). Each time a new version loads you are wiping out the plugins that were registered to the previous version of jQuery object

Use a browser console to inspect script errors. Will likely see errors like `jdpicker is not a function`

jQUery.js must load before all other dependent plugins and code

Comment: you realize that `jquery-1.8.3.js` is third instance ...correct? Only need one

Comment: thank you so much.. i removed all extra jquery declarations.. and its working fine nw..